# HTTP Error 409 while accessing registered dataset as a URI file (Azure SDKv2)

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

In Azure ML I'm trying to read data from the blob storage, register it as a `URI File`. This is needed to keep data versioning and at the same time to keep data lineage (sort of) because components require to have either `URI File` or `URI Folder`.

So, this is how I try to manage that:

```py
# Setting the credentials

subscription_id = 'my_id'
resource_group = 'my_group'
workspace_name = 'my_workspace'

workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)

# authenticate
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
credential.get_token("https://management.azure.com/.default")
# Get a handle to the workspace
ml_client = MLClient(
    credential=credential,
    subscription_id=subscription_id,
    resource_group_name=resource_group,
    workspace_name=workspace_name,
)

# Waking up "lazy" client
data_asset = ml_client.data.get(name="coffee_data", version=1)
print(f"Data asset URI: {data_asset.path}")

from azure.ai.ml.entities import Data
from azure.ai.ml.constants import AssetTypes


web_path = 'https://containername12345.blob.core.windows.net/my-container/raw_data/raw.csv'

raw_data = Data(
    name="TESTESTEST",
    path=web_path,
    type=AssetTypes.URI_FILE,
    description="Dataset for some work I do!",
    tags={"user":"Egor"},
)

data = ml_client.data.create_or_update(raw_data)
print(
    f"Dataset with name {data.name} was registered to workspace, the dataset version is {data.version}"
)
```

```
Output:
Dataset with name TESTESTEST was registered to workspace, the dataset version is 4
```

Then I try to get this data which is a `URI File` now.

```py
data_asset = ml_client.data.get(name="TESTESTEST", version = ml_client.data._get_latest_version('TESTESTEST').version)
print(f"Data asset URI: {data_asset.path}")
```

```
Output:
Data asset URI: https://containername12345.blob.core.windows.net/my-container/raw_data/raw.csv
```

And here's funny thing. If I follow this URL, which is clickable I see this:

```xml
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>PublicAccessNotPermitted</Code>
<Message>Public access is not permitted on this storage account. RequestId:abcde-12345 Time:2023-08-18T07:31:07.6896441Z</Message>
</Error>
```

Which is basically leads to the problem when I try to read data throughout this `URI file`.

```py
df = pd.read_csv(data_asset.path)
```

```
Output:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 1
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv(data_asset.path)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:912, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, date_format, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options, dtype_backend)
    899 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
    900     dialect,
    901     delimiter,
   (...)
    908     dtype_backend=dtype_backend,
    909 )
    910 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
--> 912 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

... (this contains many lines)

HTTPError: HTTP Error 409: Public access is not permitted on this storage account.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the issue:
[image]

It seems like you're trying to access the data stored in Azure Blob Storage, but you're encountering a "PublicAccessNotPermitted" error.

To access the data file with data_asset.path, you need to use the appropriate authentication method when accessing the data.

**Method 1:** You can get the `SAS Token` of your blob and use that along with your data_asset.path:

```py
data_asset_url_with_sas = f"{data_asset.path}?{sas_token}" 
df = pd.read_csv(data_asset_url_with_sas)
```

[image]

**Method 2:** You can use `connection string` of your blob storage to authenticate and then access your csv file.

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import pandas as pd
import io
import os

# Extract the container and blob name from the data_asset.path
data_asset_path = data_asset.path
container_name, blob_name = data_asset_path.replace("https://", "").split("/", 2)[1:]

# Set your storage account connection string
connection_string = "your_connection_string"


blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)

# Download the blob data into a stream
stream = io.BytesIO()
blob_client.download_blob().readinto(stream)


stream.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(stream)
```

[image]

Another possible solution is to change the access level of your storage account to public.

For more details please refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=portal).

Comment: The `connection_string` is it the one which I declared in the `web_path` variable?

Comment: No that's the Storage URL, the connection string includes the authorization information required for your application to access data from your storage account. Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1071173/where-can-i-find-storage-account-connection-string)

[doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string)

Comment: Got it, it's under Access Keys. This works solid. Thank you very much!

Comment: But the question is how can I use this kind of path for the `uri file` inside the pipeline? Because when we declare 'Input" we should use the path. So this should be from the `stream`?